# I don't want other administrator to change my password

Tags: login, password, sudo, users, root

I have one administrator account in my system which named as "admin". One more admin account called "test". I don't want test account to reset "admin" account and root account password in my system.

I have blocked sudo users by following command.

```
%sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL, !/usr/bin/passwd root,!/usr/bin/passwd admin
admin ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

It's working on when executing this command as test user. 
If test user tries

`sudo passwd root` or `sudo passwd admin`

It throws following error called

> Sorry, user test is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/passwd root' as
>   root on magesh-test.

But it's not working while executing the following command `sudo passwd $root`

How to block the test user alone in resetting the password?

Comment: What is `$root` set to?

Comment: By executing "sudo passwd $root" is changing the root password. I don't get any idea how it works?

Comment: What is the output of `echo $root`?

Comment: @MageshArumugam it works like this: `sudo passwd` by itself changes the root password. If you haven't set the variable `root` to something, `$root` is empty and the command you showed translates to simply `sudo passwd`, which you haven't restricted.

Comment: Also, this won't work in any number of ways. The `test` user can do `sudo -i`, `sudo -s`, `sudo su -`, `sudo bash`, ... (you get the idea) to get a root shell, where no restriction to `passwd` will apply.